# Feed 404 Errors

Tags: 404-error, feed, google

Before you say this has been dealt with before, please read the whole issue. 
I have Google'ed and Stackoverflowed myself to death on this.

In WMT I see 404 errors for /feed on specific posts. e.g. htt://mydomain/thispost/feed/ 
My feed is working fine for pages and categories but there is this ongoing 404 error for a feed on indivual posts.

I thought to block /feed in robots.txt but then all feeds will be blocked and I dont really know the impact from a SEO perspective.

Can someone please give me a solution or direction.

By the way my site is using WPML and WP SEO (Yoast)

Thank you in advance

Comment: go to settings and re-save permalinks page. sometimes this catches me out when I've added a custom RSS feed, this might help you.

Answer (score 1):

For all those who might hit the same problem, here is the solution:

Disable in Yoast the "remove category" option in advanced section. 
Then install this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-url/ ( do use any other plugin as this one works - yes, I tried them all)

For some reason the Yoast solution and all other plugins don't allow accessing the /feed/ url in any language besides the default language of WPML.

Hope this will be useful someone out there..